# Docker building image that needs 'y' response

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, certbot

I'm trying to install Certbot into my Nginx container, following the steps on the Certbot website: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/pip-nginx

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1

# install wget
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y

# install certbot
RUN wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
RUN mv certbot-auto /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
RUN chown root /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
RUN chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto

# get certificate
RUN /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --nginx -y

# setup automatic renewal
...
```

I build the image using docker-compose

```
$ docker-compose build
```

The build gets aborted at the '# get certificate' step

[image]

[image]

...because I'm unable to type 'y' during the build?

Is there a way I can input 'y' during the build? I've tried passing the -y flag as shown in my Dockerfile  but the build still aborts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try editing the dockerfile to pipe the `yes` command into the command that's failing:

```
RUN yes | /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --nginx -y
```

The `yes` command repeatedly outputs `y` plus the return key over and over forever. Piping it into the command results in anything that prompts for user input to be answered with `y`. It's commonly used when you don't have the ability to use a `--force` or `-y` option in a script.